# Cisco RV042 can ping gateway only

Tags: router, gateway, route, cisco-vpn

I have Cisco RV042 which the problem is can ping gateway only. here my setup :

LAN Setting Device,

```
IP address : 172.31.13.254
Netmask : 255.255.255.248
```

Dual Wan Setting WAN 1 Static IP:

```
IP Address : 202.xx.xx.254
Netmask : 255.255.255.252
Def GW : 202.xx.xx.253
DNS Server 1 IP : 202.xx.xx.36
DNS Server 1 IP : 202.xx.xx.37
MTU : Auto
```

Dual Wan Setting WAN 2 DHCP IP:

```
Obtain an IP Automatically
```

Ping Gateway 202.xx.xx.253

```
Status:     Test Succeeded
Packets:    4/4 transmitted, 4/4 received, 0% loss
Round Trip Time:    Minimun = 1 ms
Maximun = 1 ms
Average = 1 ms
```

Ping DNS 1 & 2 : 202.xx.xx.36 & 37

```
Status:     Test Failed
Packets:    4/4 transmitted, 0/4 received, 100% loss
Round Trip Time:    Minimun = 2147483647 ms
Maximun = 0 ms
Average = 0 ms
```

Ping outside IP : 8.8.8.8

```
Status:     Test Failed
Packets:    4/4 transmitted, 0/4 received, 100% loss
Round Trip Time:    Minimun = 2147483647 ms
Maximun = 0 ms
Average = 0 ms
```

What a problem with my RV042 is ?
I'm very appreciate, can give me explain about this. 
Thanks

Pathic

Comment: Are the DNS servers inside or outside?

Comment: I'm sorry, I worked out of town. dns server is inside. I think I have solution with this problem. I made NAT in my router firewall. RV02 can ping to outside but the problem is on my target RV02 IP has registered, so if with another IP public target can't accept. oh man. I must think harder to solve this problem.